# Diffrence betwen Yii::creatObject() and new keyword

Tags: yii2

What is the difference between

```
Yii::createObject(User::class, ['username' => 'Me', 'age' => 27])
```

and

```
new User('Me', 27)
```

Red some about it but it still seems equal for me. Well I saw one of the authors saying that the first one has better performance. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one has better performance, but it is no really big difference in real applications. The main difference is that `Yii::createObject()` uses [dependency injection container](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-di-container), so it is much more flexible. I will automatically resolve dependencies and you can configure your application to use different implementation of `User` as result of `Yii::createObject(User::class, ['username' => 'Me', 'age' => 27])`.

In general, you should read [guide article about DI](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-di-container) to understand features of `Yii::createObject()`, since it mostly provides syntactic sugar for creating objects using DI container.

Comment: Clear enough! Thank you!